# Create embed based of users message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm quite new to discord.py so I'm posting this here. How do I make a command so that when the user says !embed (message here) #channelhere it turns the users message into an embed and then posts it into the specified channel? An explanation would be nice to so I can try to understand it.

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far so we know where you're at and can better assist.

Comment: @PeterJones I have not written anything yet because I am unsure of what to start it with

Comment: Then you need to go look at the docs. Stack overflow is not for people to to the work for you. It's for helping people who are stuck. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code I have:

Eg: I enter !embed hello / wow

```
@bot.command() #used before a command
async def embed(ctx, *, content: str): #when the person uses !embed it will do what is under.  Ctx is needed to store the channel of the message, author of message and other properties. content is the argument, or what you put after the !embed (in this case hello / wow)- we state that it is a string(str) or plain text if that is more clear
    title, description= content.split('/') #the title and description of the embed are separated by "/" In this cas, title is "hello",description is "wow"
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=0x00ff40) #making the embed (MUST HAVE TITLE AND DESCRIPTION)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed) #sending the embed in THE SAME CHANNEL YOU SENT THE COMMAND IN (as shown via ctx)
    await ctx.message.delete() #deleting the original message by you to clean the channel up(as shown by ctx.message)
```

In terms of specific channel that might be a bit more complicated: however this should work perfectly

Comment: great!  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Basiclly you have to create a variable called `channel` that contains the channel ID, for example: `channel = bot.get_channel(636399538650742795)`. Then you create a command that takes an argument, this argument is the message to be embeded, you store the argument in a variable, make a variable called `embed`, this variable will be `embed = discord.Embed(value=argument)`, wich we will send with `await channel.send(embed=embed)`. The actual code looks like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx, argument: str):
    channel = bot.get_channel(636399538650742795)
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name="Message", value=argument)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

To get the channel ID, just right click the channel you want to get the ID of and click Copy ID. And considering that you're very new to discord.py, I am using `@bot.command()` because I am defining it with `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the 2 answers I see, you can send an embed to a specific channel whatever you want by converting the channel into the channel id.

Here's the code :

```py
@client.command()
async def echoembed(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel, *, Text : str):        # full command (!echoembed #channelhere Title here | Description here)
    Title, Description = Text.split(' | ')                                     # You need to split the arguments using |, change to other symbols whatever you want
    channel_id = channel.id                                                    # this will convert the channel name into the channel id
    channel_send = client.get_channel(channel_id)                              # we will get the channel using the channel id
    embed = discord.Embed(title = Title, description = Description, color = 0x2F3136)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()                               # this will tell the time today
    embed.set_footer(text = "\u200b", icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)        # the \u200b is an empty character
    await channel_send.send(embed = embed)                                     # and finally, we can send the embed
```

If you're fairly new to discord.py, I suggest you need to read the docs before going into complicated stuff.

The docs will be linked [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html)

Thank me later :D